# How to get the Twitter Usertimeline with Tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitterizer

I try to get the last 20 statuses of the Usertimeline. So I search in the internet and get
the follow code:

```
TwitterUser twitterUser = TwitterUser.Show("Username").ResponseObject;
if (twitterUser != null)
{
    UserTimelineOptions userTimelineOptions = new UserTimelineOptions();
    userTimelineOptions.UserId = twitterUser.Id;

    return TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(userTimelineOptions).ResponseObject;
}
return null;
```

When I test it, I get the follow exception:

```
Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Line 1, position 1795.
```

I have no idea what's wrong so I hope you can help me!

Comment: I never used twitterizer in specific, but where do you send in Login-Information? Or is this to get tweets from anybodyelse that exists?

Comment: twitterizer does not use a login. It is based on the 1.0 api and has no oAuth. really loved the library, too bad that is has no update to support 1.1 api

Answer (score 1):

Since [Twitterizer](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer#This_is_the_end) is discontinued, I assumed that you moved to [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp):

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
service.AuthenticateWith("accessToken", "accessTokenSecret");
var options = new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions();
options.ExcludeReplies = true;
var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(options);
```

For Twitterizer:

```
UserTimelineOptions options = new UserTimelineOptions();
options.ScreenName = "Username";

var tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(options).ResponseObject;
```

Twitterizer uses the 1.0 API and TweetSharp has the required oAuth for the 1.1 twitter API:
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var twitterService = new TwitterService("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
twitterService.AuthenticateWith("token", "tokenSecret");
var tweets = twitterService.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
```